# Entity Framework Function Import Trims Leading Zeros From String

Tags: entity-framework, t-sql

I have a funny issue with Entity Framework function import. I am importing a stored procedure from MS SQL Server 2008 R2, and it returns just one string. However, it is too complex for EF to infer this return type, so when defining function import I had to manually specify that the function returns a collection of scalars (`ObjectResult<global::System.String>`, as was generated).

Sometimes, the procedure returns a string containing only digits and starting with zero (e.g., `01234`). When I access this result in the code, it turns out to be without the starting zero (`1234`)!

I know several workarounds, so it is not a question. I want to understand what's going on.

My wild guess is that in my case - when SP is too complex to "predict" its result - EF first tries to "guess" the type of the returned data by the format of that data. I.e., it sees a number (`01234`), and converts it into integer type (`int`, `short` - whatever). Then it sees that I want a `string`, and converts this number back into `string`, but of course during these conversions starting zero is lost. Is that true, or is there a better explanation?

UPDATE: This is a screenshot for function import:

[image: Function Import]

Comment: EF should not guess the data format. Can you show your stored procedure and mapping?

Comment: Can't you just change the return type to a string and then manually parse the results in the manner you expect?

Comment: 2Ryan - I know lots of workarounds, I am not asking for them

Comment: 2Pawel - I cannot disclose the stored procedure. I can fake one, if you really need this, but the matter is that it has several points where it selects the result, each of the points selects only one string. I am using EF's UI to add function import, and it says "The selected stored procedure returns no columns." when I click "Get Column Information". So EF cannot generate result type for me, and I explicitly specify that the SP returns collection of strings.